# reloadRowsAtIndexPaths crashing; reloadData working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My app crashes when I am trying to reload a couple of rows as follows:

```
[tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

However, the code works fine when I replace the line by :

```
[tblView reloadData];
```

The crash that I get is

> > libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Do you have enough rows in table which you are reloading ?

Comment: I think you are gonna give us a bit more information than this... What is the context of the those lines? E.g., rowsToReload might point to rows that are not in the table, thus causing something similar as index out of range exception.

Comment: try passing `rowsToReload` as an array.

Comment: reloadData will reload the entire table. ReloadRowsAtIndexPath will only reload the given indexPath, I am guessing that there seems to be some changes in your data which was not reflected properly with your data source?  maybe change in section? not much information on your post so I am just guessing

Comment: Could you sow the full crash log?

Comment: Make sure, Reloading occurs only on visible Cells

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];

[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.3];

[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction 
functionWithControlPoints:0 :1.8 :0 :1]];

[self.menuCollectionView performBatchUpdates:^{
  [tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];

[CATransaction commit];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

use as

```
 NSIndexPath* indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0];

 NSArray* indexArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];

 [tblView  reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexArray withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your indexPath like below.

```
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0];
[tblView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```